# uib-datepicker-popup issue with Angular ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<input class="form-control" 
       uib-datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" 
       ng-readonly="!isEditable"
       datepicker-append-to-body="true" 
       ng-model="logicalDepotVo.rtCreationDate"
       is-open="isDatepickerOpen" 
       placeholder="Enter Creation Date"
       ng-click="isEditable ? onCreationDateDatepickerClick() : ''"/>
```

The value does not view value of model, but bind model works as `ng-model`. When I removed `uib-datepicker-popup`, all works fine. I tried to remove custom format, play with other attributes, but have no any successful result. Maybe, somebody has an idea what should be done?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a working example. What are your `angular.js` and `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` versions? [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/a57COQVTBmE3Dr7jj6EC?p=preview)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey
AngularJS v1.4.14
angular-ui-bootstrap 2.1.4

Comment: it's best to have 1.7.2 angularjs (_or around 1.6.X_) and 2.5.0 ui-bootstrap

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I'd like to have this, but current project is very huge and has many dependencies of different versions. I'm afraid that task to update front-end libraries is wide for now. Could you, please, help me with those library versions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this could explain your issue (check you ng-model for correct date format):
ng-model - The date object. Must be a Javascript Date object. You may use the uibDateParser service to assist in string-to-object conversion.
[angularjs bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.